# writing a client over websocket in golang

Tags: go, websocket

I'm writing an client that dials a websocket, and waits to receive information. I can successfully dial the websocket, but I cannot figure out how to implement some kind of asynchronous callback using the "golang.org/x/net/websocket" package. Is this even possible, or should I use the Gorilla package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop to read a websocket using the Gorilla package:

```
for {
    _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("read:", err)
        c.Close()
        break
    }
    handleMessage(message)
}
```

Run the loop in a goroutine to make it asynchronous:

```
go func() {
    for {
        _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            c.Close()
            break
        }
        handleMessage(message)
    }
}()
```

Comment: Is "golang.org/x/net/websocket" still inferior to gorilla?

Comment: The x/net package does not implement the complete protocol including commonly used features like message fragmentation. Use the Gorilla package.

Comment: Yes i am also finding same .. i have also check gorilla package but 
need write callback like javascript as
onconnect, onmessage, onerror, onclose, onsend, onreconnect